# Best Practice for Inline binding with XAML and text Text="Some text {Some binding} some more text}"

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I'm wondering if there is special syntax to bind text concatenated with existing text.

Something like this.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="tbGroupMembershipCaption"
           Text="The following users have access to export to '{Binding TargetName}'."/>
```

Clearly, this doesn't work.

What is the best practice?

Using SL4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) on the `Binding`.

**WPF:** `{Binding SomeProp, StringFormat={}Head text {0} Tail text}`
**WPF/SL:** `{Binding SomeProp, StringFormat='{}Head text {0} Tail text'}`
**WPF/SL Alt.:** `{Binding SomeProp, StringFormat=Head text \{0\} Tail text}`

Comment: This example doesn't work at all and leaves me with the following error:Error 1 Unexpected token Open in Rule: MarkupExtension ::= '{' TYPENAME (Arguments)? @'}', in '{Binding TargetName, StringFormat=The following users have access to export to {0}}'.

Comment: @user1060500: Are you sure you included the `{}` at the beginning of the format string, *they are important* (at least in compiled XAML).

Comment: <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="tbGroupMembershipCaption" Text="{Binding TargetName, StringFormat={}The following users have access to export to {0}}" ></TextBlock> results in this error Unexpected Token after end of Markup Extension.

Comment: @user1060500: If you put a WPF tag on a question and test the answers you are given in Silverlight you should not be surprised that they just may not work.

Comment: I mentioned SL4 in my post.  Thanks for clearing up that there is a difference in the syntax between SL and WPF.

Comment: @user1060500: Actually according to the SL documentation the double braces act as an escape as well, but it's not very specific about it. **Edit:** Apparently it's more strict about the string delimiting, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
Text="{Binding TargetName, StringFormat=The following users have access to export to \{0\}}"
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx for more details.

Comment: This example doesn't work at all and leaves me with the following error:Error 1 Unexpected token Open in Rule: MarkupExtension ::= '{' TYPENAME (Arguments)? @'}', in '{Binding TargetName, StringFormat=The following users have access to export to {0}}'.

Comment: I've updated the above using the Silverlight \ escape sequence. Please retry.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2010/05/28/silverlight-4-binding-and-stringformat-in-xaml/):

```
Text="{Binding TargetName, StringFormat=The following users have access to export to '\{0\}'."
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Close to the last one but that one would not work for me.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding       CreatedBy, StringFormat=By \{0\}}"/>
```